# Rerender Flatlist after Call api then setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist, rerender

I just started learning React native, and want to render FlaList after setState.
I am try to call Api to get Data and then I sorting that data but the FlatList is not rerender with newData. I also try `extraData` but nothing happen. Where am I missing?

Thank for your help.

```
function HomeScreen(props) {
    const {transactions = []} = useSelector(selectors.transactions) || [];
    const [listTransaction, setListTransaction] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(BalanceActions.balanceRequest()); // This is my call Api
  
        sortListTransaction(); // I call sortFunc after that
    }, []);

    const sortListTransaction = () => { // In this function I group by date the array of the result Api
        let groups = [];

        transaction.forEach((item) => {
            let date = moment(item.date).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
            if (date in groups) {
                groups[date].push(item);
            } else {
                groups[date] = new Array(item);
            }
        });

        setListTransaction(groups);
    };

    const _renderItem = ({item}) => {
        return <BodyContent data={item} />;
    };

    // Then my FlatList like:
    return (
        <FlatList
            data={listTransaction}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
            renderItem={_renderItem}
            extraData={listTransaction}
        />
    )
}
```

Comment: And by adding `listTransaction` in the useEffect dependencies?

Comment: No. It the same.

Comment: where/when is `transaction` updated? I think when `setListTransaction(groups)` is called, groups is empty.

Comment: `transactions` updated after I call Api. When I log `listTransaction` it still right, but FlatList is not rerender

Comment: When the ```date``` is not in ```groups``` you're adding an ```Array``` as a Item of the ```groups``` array. Is this can be the problem? I don't think ```FlatList``` can read array of arrays.